# My Public Key on MultiBit Classic is 34 digits long

Tags: public-key, multibit

My public key, as it's displayed in MultiBit Classic, has remained unchanged in the last eight years since I bought my bitcoin in Jan 2014.  I'm now looking to move my bitcoins from MultiBit Classic to Coinbase.  But since MultiBit is deprecated, I need to extract the public key and private key from MultiBit, and send it manually from Exodus.  I have been able to extract the private keys, and confirm they are the correct length: 52 digits for a compressed public key.  My public key is 34 digits, but everywhere I read says a compressed public key should be 33 digits.  What am I missing? or not understanding correctly.

How can I confirm the correct compressed public key?

This question:
[MultiBit with multiple addresses to Electrum](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102721/multibit-with-multiple-addresses-to-electrum)
explains how to export a private key from MultiBit Classic.  I already have my private keys, but my public keys are 1 digit too long.

Comment: What do the public keys you're talking about look like? Are they human-readable? Hexadecimal? Base58? byte arrays starting with 0x02 or 0x03?

Comment: After you import your private keys, Exodus should be able to regenerate your public keys from that. Why do you need to export the public keys?

Comment: @PieterWuille, they're alphanumeric, no special characters, and start with "1F12RWoivL3t ....." and "1Q1UtS5veqZF ...", and are 34 digits so I concluded that the public keys are compressed.

Comment: @Murch, I believe I need the public key that is associated with each private key to manually send bitcoin from Exodus to Coinbase.

Comment: What you are describing are addresses which are stand-ins for the public keys, but not the public keys themselves.—After you import private keys, your wallet should rescan the blockchain for funds. As soon as it has rediscovered the relevant funds, it will be able to spend them in a transaction. It's not clear why you would need the address in order to send somewhere else: Coinbase should give you a unique deposit address in order to distinguish which account to credit.

Comment: If anything, you might need the address to identify which private key to exactly export to the other wallet, but you write that you have already successfully extracted the private keys.—Anyway, it sounds to me like you may be trying to do something that you don't need.